# Cannot ping a server. Wan over vlan on Cisco/Linksys switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, wide-area-network, linksys

I have an old, but mostly unused Cisco/Linksys slm224g4s switch and Mikrotik B2011UiAS-RM router. On a switch I've configured three vlans, two for WAN1 (id:3) and WAN2 (id:4) and third for LAN (id:2).

My current port configuration

```
port number - designation - port2vlan - port setting pvid
1 - WAN1 input - 2 excl, 3 excl, 4 untagged - 4
2 - WAN2 input - 2 excl, 3 untagged, 4 excl - 3
3-12 servers - 2 tagged, 3 tagged, 4 tagged - 2
13 - WAN1 to router - 2 excl, 3 excl, 4 untagged - 4
14 - WAN2 to router - 2 excl, 3 untagged, 4 excl - 3
15-24 servers - 2 tagged, 3 tagged, 4 tagged - 2
G1 - LAN from router - 2 untagged, 3 excl, 4 excl - 2
G2-G4 servers - 2 tagged, 3 tagged, 4 tagged - 2
```

Configuration in admin panel: http://s3.fmdx.pl/public/cisco/

Mikrotik router combines these two WAN connections from two ISPs to make more reliable internet connection and works as a router for the whole company.

We have two, 8 IP addresses blocks from both ISPs, router takes only one IP from each ISP to provide internet access. Remaining IP addresses are used for company servers (files, erp, testing/dev servers, etc..). Mtu is 1500 everywhere.

/etc/network/interfaces configuration looks like this on a temporary server:

```
# LAN
auto enp1s0.2
iface enp1s0.2 inet static
        address 10.1.4.10
        gateway 10.1.0.1
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        dns-nameservers 10.1.0.1
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500

# Netia
allow-hotplug enp1s0.3
iface enp1s0.3 inet static
        address 192.168.0.72
        gateway 192.168.0.65
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500

# Connected
allow-hotplug enp1s0.4
iface enp1s0.4 inet static
        address 192.168.1.168
        gateway 192.168.1.161
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500
```

- WAN IP addresses in this example are not real.

Vlan package is installed, 8021q module is on, first vlan interface (LAN) works just fine, I can ping anything through that interface.

Unfortunately I cannot ping anything using second and third vlan interface, also the server is not accessible from the internet.

ifup enp1s0.3 or enp1s0.4 returns

```
Set name-type for VLAN subsystem. Should be visible in /proc/net/vlan/config
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up enp1s0.3
```

ifdown enp1s0.3 or enp1s0.4

```
ifdown: interface enp1s0.3 not configured
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you set the routing? Otherwise all non-LAN packets will use the default route. Post your routing table. I believe you are trying to set a "split-wan" setup.

Comment: Check the question I posted a while ago: https://serverfault.com/questions/889085/split-access-from-multiple-uplinks/893848#893848

Comment: @quimnuss thank you for advice, after fiddling with routing scripts i've managed to get it working. These scripts seem to run out of order on startup

Comment: Glad I helped indirectly. Post your solution/answer to help somebody who ends up having the same problem. Or remove the question if it was too localised / misjudged.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Everything runs fine now. What was the problem.

I forgot to copy a few scripts we deploy on each server and one of them includes this bash code:

```
# Connected routing
ip route add "$ISP1_NET" dev "$ISP1_IF" src "$ISP1_IP" table "$ISP1_NAME"
ip route add default via "$ISP1_GW" table "$ISP1_NAME"
ip rule add from "$ISP1_IP" table "$ISP1_NAME"
ip rule add from all to "$ISP1_CHECK_IP" table "$ISP1_NAME"

# Netia routing
ip route add "$ISP2_NET" dev "$ISP2_IF" src "$ISP2_IP" table "$ISP2_NAME"
ip route add default via "$ISP2_GW" table "$ISP2_NAME"
ip rule add from "$ISP2_IP" table "$ISP2_NAME"
ip rule add from all to "$ISP2_CHECK_IP" table "$ISP2_NAME"
```

Also I had to change allow-hotplug to auto in /etc/network/interfaces to make it work after reboot, and modify few variables in config file.

These problems are the worst when you waste your time and the solution is this simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided is not quite correct eg. you will still get error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` while trying to restart networking or restarting a machine.

For status on debian stretch execute

```
systemctl status networking.service
```

Your routes will not work unless you execute script manually again.

#### First

You have setup `gateway 10.1.0.1` with `netmask 255.255.252.0` where host max can be 10.1.3.254 with `broadcast 10.1.3.255`

Check [IP Calculator / IP Subnetting](http://jodies.de/ipcalc)

#### Second

You can have only one default gateway. When you assign eg `gateway 10.1.0.1` to interface, it will try to assign it as default, if there is already one default gateway you will get error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.

Correct configuration should be

```
# LAN
auto enp1s0.2
iface enp1s0.2 inet static
        address 10.1.3.254/22 # (max host!) 
        gateway 10.1.0.1
        dns-nameservers 10.1.0.1
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500

# Netia
auto enp1s0.3
iface enp1s0.3 inet static
        address 192.168.0.72/20
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500
        up ip route add 192.168.0.0/20 via 192.168.0.65 ...
        up ...

# Connected
auto enp1s0.4
iface enp1s0.4 inet static
        address 192.168.1.168/20
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        vlan-raw-device enp1s0
        mtu 1500
        up ip route add 192.168.0.0/20 via 192.168.1.161 ...
        up ...
```

Please note as I mentioned previously you cannot add multiple default routes as `ip route add default via ...`.

After you configure it correctly your `auto|allow-auto|allow-hotplug [interface]` should work, but you should check link for [more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192671/what-is-a-hotplug-event-from-the-interface#192913) details.

Hope this helps.